# Changing HTML inside a div with a class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to modify the HTML with a class based on the information submitted.

Here is the default element

```
<div class="form-login-error">
    <h3>Invalid password</h3>
    <p>You have submitted an invalid password.</p>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change the `<h3>` and `<p>` text within my .js file, however, I am not sure how to modify the HTML directly.

Comment: Indicate your JS file then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// if you want to place js code in separate file then import file to your html file 
window.onload = function () {
   var div = document.querySelector('.form-login-error');

   div.querySelector('h3').innerText = 'your h3 text'
   div.querySelector('p').innerText = 'your paragraph text'
}

<div class="form-login-error">
<h3>Invalid password</h3>
<p>You have submitted an invalid password.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work, May I note the js file is added to the login.php file as <script src="assets/js/neon-login.js"></script>

Comment: thanks, wrap js code within window.onload function as corrected in answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `<div>` by classname

   ```
    // this will get the first element with this class
   const div = document.querySelector('.form-login-error')
   ```
2. You can then access the child elements and their content like this

   ```
   div.querySelector('h3').textContent = 'Something else'
   div.querySelector('p').textContent = 'Some more detail'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Get your element first**

```
var elementsWithClassName = document.getElementsByClassName('form-login-error');
// get your div element
var yourDivElementWithFormLoginError = elementsWithClassName[0];
```

**By using element.innerHTML**

```
// use innerHTML
yourDivElementWithFormLoginError.innerHTML = '<i>your desired text</i>';
/*
 Your element's current innerHTML is 
 '<h3>Invalid password</h3><p>You have submitted an invalid password.</p>'
*/
```

**By using element.elements**

If you don't want to change all of the inner contents or want to make change to each of your elements ( *p* and *h3* ), you can use *elements* property which represents child elements inside *yourDivElementWithFormLoginError*.

```
// get your h3 element
var h3Element = yourDivElementWithFormLoginError.elements[0];
// change content like this
h3Element.innerHTML = 'your desire HTML text';
// or like this
h3Element.textContent = 'your desire text'

// And again
// get your p element
var pElement = yourDivElementWithFormLoginError.elements[1];
// can change your pElement like h3Element
```

P.S. You can alter only the text inside the element with **element.textContent** but you can add or change HTML content (not just text) with **element.innerHTML**

Comment: Will this work if I am adding the js file as a script? because it does not seem to be working..... (How im importing the .js file: <script src="assets/js/neon-login.js"></script>)

Comment: By adding .js file or writing inside <script> , both should be working fine. May be uour codes is working before elements have loaded. Write your logic inside event functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the HTML with `innerHTML`. Here is my sample code:

HTML

```
<div class="form-login-error">
    <h3 id = "h3Text">Invalid password</h3>
    <p id = "pText">You have submitted an invalid password.</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("h3Text").innerHTML = "Text...";
document.getElementById("pText").innerHTML = "Text...";
```

Or if you prefer, JQuery

```
$("#h3Text").text("Text...");
$("#pText").text("Text...");
```

In my samples, I added the h3Text and pText `id`'s to your `h3` and `p` so I could later change them in JavaScript or JQuery via accessing them by `id`.